# How to read raw data from sd card in R

Tags: r

I want to read data from a SD card into R. There is no data format on the SD card, so I am looking for a way to read the data raw.

Is there a packet which allows reading and writing byte by byte to an (external) hard disk?

I have seen that there is a possibility [to execute system commands in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html). With this I could call the dd tool under UNIX. However, a native function in R would be my favorite.

Like in UNIX: (but in R)

```sh
dd if=/dev/sdcard of=/home/user/sdcard.hex bs=512 count=1
```

Comment: My goal was to keep the portability of the R code as high as possible. As mentioned in the article, I could call dd from R, but I am also interested in alternative methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dd` simply performs raw read and write from and to a given file or device. You can do the same in R using `readBin`:

```r
result = readBin('/dev/sdcard', 'raw', 512L)
```

The result is of type `raw`, which loosely corresponds to bytes in R.

However, note that this is *not* portable to Windows, since addressing devices works differently here. I think on Windows you need to use a UNC path, something like `\\.\PhysicalDrive‹#›`, where `‹#›` is the drive number.

Comment: Thank you very much. Reading from `/dev/mmcblk0` works fine, but I don't see any option in `writeBin` or `readBin` to pass the beginning of reading/writing. Both functions read/write always from beginning of the physical device, which is against my use-case. I guess I cannot cover this case in R without invoking system-commands.

Comment: @E.Yagmahan Yes you can: You just need to create the file connection separately and pass it (repeatedly) into `readBin`, or invoke `seek` on it.